# How can I identify spam traffic?

Tags: spam-prevention

Recently I am getting some referrals traffic which are everyday changing their name (I am blocking them everyday from GA). First few days their name was example.xyz but now they are using various name. All the traffic's are coming from Russia. They are only landing to / and nowhere. How can I identify that it's a spam traffic or not?

Comment: There are two fast ways. One is to compare what you see in GA with what you see in your log file analyzer. What?! You do not have a log file analyzer? I suggest Piwik. It is free and one of the best of the best. The other way to know spam is to look for the word Hormel on the can. (humor) Actually, it is to get a feel for what is real and what is not over a period of time. You will get a sixth sense for this quickly. Trust me on this! Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a [hostname filter](https://www.fourfront.us/blog/using-the-hostname-filter-for-accurate-google-analytics-data), this will block 90% of referral spam which won't originate from your own server hostname (yoursite.com).

Answer (score 0):

Make your code see if the typical resources of the main page were also loaded. Automated robots usually only load a single URL and then nothing for a long time from that particular address.